cannot move out of `whitelist_tree.merkle_tree` which is behind a shared reference
move occurs because whitelist_tree.merkle_tree has type MerkleTree, which does not implement the Copy trait :-
use {
    super::WhitelistArgs,
    crate::instructions::{transfer_tokens, whitelist::Tree, TransferTokensArgs, WHITELIST_TREE},
    borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize},
    merkletreers::{tree::MerkleTree, utils::hash_it},
    solana_program::{
        account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
        clock::Clock,
        entrypoint::ProgramResult,
        msg,
        program::invoke,
        program_error::ProgramError,
        system_instruction,
        sysvar::Sysvar,
    },
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct PreSaleArgs {
    pub pre_sale_price: u64,
    pub pre_sale_limit: u64,
    pub pre_sale_start_time: u64,
    pub pre_sale_end_time: u64,
    pub quantity: u64,
    pub price: u64,
    pub account: bool,
}

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct BuyerArgs {
    pub buy_quantity: u64,
}

pub fn pre_sale(
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    args: PreSaleArgs,
    white_list_args: WhitelistArgs,
    buyer_args: BuyerArgs,
    whitelist_tree: &Tree, 
) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let seller_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let buyer_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let system_program = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    let current_time = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp as u64;
    if current_time < args.pre_sale_start_time || current_time > args.pre_sale_end_time {
        return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument);
    }

    msg!("Pre sale has started!");

    let root = whitelist_tree.merkle_tree.root; 

    msg!("{:?}", root);

    let buyer = buyer_account.key.to_string();

    let mut leaf = [0u8; 32];
    hash_it(buyer.as_bytes(), &mut leaf);
    let proof = whitelist_tree.merkle_tree.make_proof(leaf);
    msg!("Proof: {:?}", proof);

    let result = whitelist_tree.merkle_tree.check_proof(proof, leaf);
    msg!("result: {:?}", result);


    let amount = TransferTokensArgs {
        quantity: buyer_args.buy_quantity,
    };
    let total_cost = amount.quantity * args.pre_sale_price;

    let transfer_sol =
        system_instruction::transfer(buyer_account.key, seller_account.key, total_cost);
    invoke(
        &transfer_sol,
        &[
            buyer_account.clone(),
            seller_account.clone(),
            system_program.clone(),
        ],
    )?;

    transfer_tokens(accounts, amount)?;

    Ok(())
}

This is the white list code :-
use {
    borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize},
    merkletreers::{tree::MerkleTree, utils::hash_it},
    solana_program::{entrypoint::ProgramResult, msg, program_error::ProgramError},
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct WhitelistArgs {
    pub accounts: Vec<String>,
}

const ADMIN_ACCOUNT: &str = "Cv66dQwcSJDdXNVHybchYqp73d75Y8XWj6pKcjN3ffAy";

pub struct Tree {
    pub merkle_tree: MerkleTree,
}

pub(crate) static mut WHITELIST_TREE: Option<Tree> = None;

pub fn whitelist_account(args: WhitelistArgs, admin_account: String) -> ProgramResult {
    if admin_account != ADMIN_ACCOUNT {
        return Err(ProgramError::IllegalOwner);
    }

    let leaves: Vec<[u8; 32]> = args
        .accounts
        .iter()
        .map(|account_str| {
            let account_bytes = account_str.as_bytes();
            let mut buffer = [0u8; 32];
            hash_it(account_bytes, &mut buffer);
            buffer
        })
        .collect();

    let whitelist_tree = MerkleTree::new(leaves);

    let tree = Tree {
        merkle_tree: whitelist_tree,
    };

    msg!("Accounts have been added to the whitelist");
    msg!("{:?}", tree.merkle_tree.root);

    unsafe {
        WHITELIST_TREE = Some(tree);
    }

    Ok(())
}


Please provide some more information about exactly where the error is triggered, it's very difficult to figure it out from so much code!
